# Recurrence relation to check if a binary tree is a binary search tree

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, pseudocode, recurrence

Can someone help me please with recurrence relation for this pseudo code? This pseudo code describes a procedure that check if a binary tree is a binary search tree.  I think its:

```
T(n) = T(n/2) +1
```

Code:

```
IsBST(node, answer ← true) 
    if node!= null then
         if node.right!= null then
             if  node.key < node.right.key then
                  IsBST(node.right, answer)
             else
                 answer ← false
                return answer

         if node.left!= null then
             if  node.key > node.left.key then
                  IsBST(node.left, answer)
             else
                 answer ← false
                return answer

    return answer
```

Comment: Can you give more precision on your question? The algorithm is a recursive one and seems to be simple if you already have some knowledge of recursive  algorithms.

Comment: I want to know what is the recurrence relation of this algorithm. I think it's T(n) = T(n/2) + 1 but I'm not sure how to approach it exactly, it's my intuition..

Comment: What is T? The complexity of the algorithm? I do not use the same notation as you do.

Comment: Assuming that n is the height of the tree, it should be: T(n) = 2*T(n-1) + 2; the constant can differ depending on which operations you are counting.

Comment: @innoSPG can you explain how did you get to  T(n) = 2*T(n-1) + 2 ?

Comment: If n is the height of the tree. when you have a tree of height n, you check the left and the right branches which are height n-1 each; In addition, you do some operation on the first node, the test; those operations define the constant. Again, this is if n is the height.

Comment: The question seems strongly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22733702/pseudo-code-to-check-if-binary-tree-is-a-binary-search-tree-not-sure-about-the by the same author.